# How to use a singleton service from CoreModule inside SharedModule Pipe in Angular (2+)

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, pipe

I have the following top-level structure of modules:

- core
- shared
- app

inside the shared module is a pipe which needs to use a service from the core module.

At the moment Angular is throwing an error when trying to use the pipe: `inline template:null:null caused by: No provider for [object Object]!`

How would I go about doing this?

The core module is imported by the app module with .forRoot() and has the service required listed as a provider (on the core module).

Comment: Can you reproduce it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you exported you components from other modules?

For example:

core.module.ts

```
  exports: [
    NavigationComponent,
    BreadcrumbsComponent,
    CommonModule
  ]
```

Comment: the core module currently only houses application wide singleton services in my case.

Comment: the shared module does have exported components and the pipe is exported here too